# jQuery: get child attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="">sometext<img src="images/001.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="">sometext<img src="images/002.jpg" /></a>
    ...
    <a href="">sometext<img src="images/nnn.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

All i want is make 'href' atrributes equal to 'src' attribute of child 'img' using jQuery. This is my unsuccessful attempt (no js-error, but without result):

```
$('div a').attr('href', $(this).children('img').attr('src'));
```

How i can get 'src' attribute of child 'img' for use like attr() second argument for parent 'a'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div a').attr('href', function() {
  return $(this).find('img').attr('src');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/299/)**

Comment: @thecodeparadox thank you.
If i know that img is always only one level descendant, can i use 'children()' method (is it better or faster?).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('div a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop each `img` and set the parent `href` attribute like this :

```
$('div a img').each(function() {
   $(this).parent().attr('href',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/QStkd/300/)